# If $f(x,y)$ is integrable and $\int f(x,y) dx \leq 0$ for a.e. $y$, then do we have $f(x,y) \leq 0$ for a.e. $(x,y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f : [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function such that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 f(x,y) dx \leq 0
\end{equation}
for a.e. $y \in [0,1]$.

Then, I wonder if $f(x,y) \leq 0$ for a.e. $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$.

I tried to approach by decomposing $f$ into its positive and negative parts, but it seems quite confusing.. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all, let for example $f(x,y)= 1-3x$, then the integrals are negative for all $y\in[0,1]$. But $f>0$ on a set with positive measure.

Comment: Oops..I was so stupid...thank you...

Comment: Happens to the best of us! :)